# Terraform aws_lambda_function Requires Docker Image In ECR

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecr

I have a module that creates all the infrastructure needed for a lambda including the ECR that stores the image:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "image_storage" {
  name                 = "${var.project}/${var.environment}/lambda"
  image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"

  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "executable" {
  function_name = var.function_name
  image_uri     = "${aws_ecr_repository.image_storage.repository_url}:latest"
  package_type  = "Image"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda.arn
}
```

The problem with this of course is that it fails because when aws_lambda_function runs the repository is there but the image is not: the image is uploaded using my CI/CD.

So this is a chicken egg problem. Terraform is supposed to only be used for infrastructure so I cannot/should not use it to upload an image (even a dummy one) but I cannot instantiate the infrastructure unless the image is uploaded in between repository and lambda creation steps.

The only solution I can think of is to create ECR separately from the lambda and then somehow link it as an existing aws resource in my lambda but that seems kind of clumsy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, separate creation is what is usually done in such a case.

Comment: Btw. you're providing the repository url to the image_uri, not a docker image url so this won't work anyway. A repository can contain multiple docker images. It should look more or less like this `${aws_ecr_repository.image_storage.repository_url}/imageName:latest`. So you need to create an ECR separatly first, then upload the image and then create the lambda...

Comment: This is the only way I have found to build a dcontainerized lambda, push to ECR and use in an APIGateway https://hands-on.cloud/terraform-deploy-python-lambda-container-image/

Comment: Running across the same, what did you end up with? I thought possibly having it create a dummy image. Also for the deployment, how are you updating the lambda version?

Comment: @Baron I posted a solution. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 11):

I ended up using the following solution where a dummy image is uploaded as part resource creation.

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "listing" {
  name                 = "myLambda"
  image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"

  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      docker pull alpine
      docker tag alpine dummy_container
      docker push dummy_container
    EOT
  }
}
```

Comment: With `docker push dummy_container` you'd push to the official Docker repository (`docker.io/library/dummy_container`), which leads to a _denied: requested access to the resource is denied_ error. How did you actually handle the pushing?

Comment: Got it working with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757907/3318377).

Answer (score 2):

Building off @przemek-lach's answer plus @halloei's comment, I wanted to post a fully-working ECR repository that gets provisioned with a dummy image

```
data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "repository" {
  name                 = "lambda-${local.name}-${local.environment}"
  image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"
  tags = local.common_tags
  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # This is a 1-time execution to put a dummy image into the ECR repo, so 
    #    terraform provisioning works on the lambda function. Otherwise there is
    #    a chicken-egg scenario where the lambda can't be provisioned because no
    #    image exists in the ECR
    command     = <<EOF
      docker login ${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint} -u AWS -p ${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password}
      docker pull alpine
      docker tag alpine ${aws_ecr_repository.repository.repository_url}:SOME_TAG
      docker push ${aws_ecr_repository.repository.repository_url}:SOME_TAG
      EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you handle the installation of docker, which is required to run the script in the local-exec?

Comment: also, how do you deal with authentication when running the aws cli command?

Comment: 2 very good callouts. If you're running this locally it isn't a problem (which I was doing when I was messing around with this). If you have a hosted terraform solution for an internal PR bot, this gets trickier.  Docker would need to be installed on the machine running the terraform command (which is definitely not a given), and for AWS auth I'm not sure the best secure way to set that up. But I would guess using environment variables would be the way to go

Comment: I used an `aws sts assume-role` command in the provisioner to get the required AWS access. Regarding docker, I am running Terraform on a GitLab runner that has docker installed, so no issues there (I'm using the same assume-role trick to authenticate to AWS and do the docker login)