# Terraform: Is it possible to define an empty image based lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, containers, terraform-provider-aws

When defining a lambda of `package_type = Zip`, it's possible to create a dummy `temp.zip` file and set it as the lambda's filename.

When created, the lambda will basically have an empty zip, which can later be replaced by something like a continuous delivery pipeline that pushes an artifact to it.

I've noticed this pattern used at work.

However, I'm playing with lambda container images for something personal.

I set it `package_type = Image`, and set other `required` arguments (per the Terraform docs). But when I run `terraform apply`, I get an error saying the lambda's `image_uri` argument must be set.

What if I don't have an image built yet? Is there some equivalent technique to satisfy the `image_uri` requirement, to essentially create an "empty" lambda, which I later plan to update via a CD pipeline?

Been looking around but have not yet found a solution.

Comment: Can you provide your relevant terraform config & exact output / error msg?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Comment: @Marcin your answer makes sense. When doing the equivalent using a Zip package type, I have to provide a dummy zip file just so that the Lambda can be created. Guess it makes sense that the same is true when using an Image; you have to provide some initial "value" for the resource to be created, even if it's a dummy image that does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if I don't have an image built yet?

Then you can't create container lambda. You have to provide some image url. It can be dummy image that does nothing, but it must preexist before you can create such a lambda function.

Then later you can update the dummy image with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74395215/5323600), which I've copied below

```
data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "repository" {
  name                 = "lambda-${local.name}-${local.environment}"
  image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"
  tags = local.common_tags
  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # This is a 1-time execution to put a dummy image into the ECR repo, so 
    #    terraform provisioning works on the lambda function. Otherwise there is
    #    a chicken-egg scenario where the lambda can't be provisioned because no
    #    image exists in the ECR
    command     = <<EOF
      docker login ${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint} -u AWS -p ${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password}
      docker pull alpine
      docker tag alpine ${aws_ecr_repository.repository.repository_url}:SOME_TAG
      docker push ${aws_ecr_repository.repository.repository_url}:SOME_TAG
      EOF
  }
}
```