# Docker login --password-stdin seems to be broken in PS, I can log in with password in CLI, but not with stdin

Tags: docker, powershell, terraform

I am new to terraform and this whole deal with docker is driving me crazy, for the past two days I have been trying to make terraform to build a docker image, tried writing it from scratch, that was awful and unintuitive so I decided to use some module Anton Babenko wrote, needless to say that did not work if I'm here.

Then I tried to rewrite the whole thing for the third time but use a provisioner block with  PS commands to build and push the image, instead of relying on terraform to do so, which always seems to fail.

```
   provisioner "local-exec" {
      interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
      command     = <<EOF
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login https://${local.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${local.region}.amazonaws.com/v2/ -u AWS --password-stdin 
cd docker
docker build -t ${local.image_name}:${local.image_tag} . 
docker push ${local.image_name}:${local.image_tag}
EOF
  }
}
```

When i try this individually:
(Yes, the ***my actual*** variables are only to redact personal info, the correct info is present in the actual requests)

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login https://*my actual account id*.dkr.ecr.*my actual region*.amazonaws.com/v2/ -u AWS --password-stdin
```

**Output:**

`Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://*my actual accout id*.dkr.ecr.*my actual region*.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request`

AWS ECR returns the correct password, but for whatever reason --password-stdin does NOT catch it properly, something breaks.

because when i try:

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login https://*my actual account id*.dkr.ecr.*my actual region*.amazonaws.com/v2/ -u AWS -p *my actual pw*
```

**Output:**

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
```

I also tried:

```
aws ecr get-login-password > pw.txt
cat ./pw.txt | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin *my actual account id*.dkr.ecr.*my actual region*.amazonaws.com
```

Also returns 400.

If I just put the password in the code, it seems to work and build the image, but it doesnt push it for some reason, I get an error there too.
Docker seems to be a downward spiral of a learning experience...

**EDIT:**
I seem to have misunderstood the use of docker login, instad of image name I should pass a repo url... silly me!

```
${local.image_name}
```

Should be:

```
${aws_ecr_repository.*my repo*.repository_url}
```

But the --password-stdin issue persists, unfortunately.

***SOLVED!***

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, please post it _as an answer_, don't edit it into the question (which you'll be able to self-accept after 48 hours).

Comment: The --password-stdin issue is related to this: https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/issues/270

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

I seem to have figured it out, my approach was wrong. TF takes care of the ecr auth token by providing a data source:

```
data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {}

resource "null_resource" "local-image" {
  triggers = {
    js_file     = filemd5(local.file_loc)
    docker_file = filemd5(local.dockerfile_loc)
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
    command     = <<EOF
docker login ${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint} -u AWS -p ${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password}
cd docker
docker build -t ${aws_ecr_repository.my-repo.repository_url}:${local.image_tag} .
docker push ${aws_ecr_repository.my-repo.repository_url}:${local.image_tag}
EOF
  }
  depends_on = [
    data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token
  ]
}
```

This works flawlessly, and `data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password` is set as `sensitive` and is properly redacted from console outputs.